# Rails 3 - Trying to parse JSON and return hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a simple two-page web-app that allows users to search for words, then display their definitions on a new page.

The problem is that when searching for a word, I'm not getting any response back from my model file.

I think the problem is trying to convert the JSON request to a hash, then accessing/displaying the hash in the view (not sure how to go about this).

---

app/views/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "search-form" %>    
    <%= submit_tag nil, :class => "search-glass", :src => "search-icon.png", :type => "image" %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/words_controller.rb

```
def search
    @word = Word.search(params[:search])
        render layout: "application", template: "words/index"
end
```

app/models/word.rb

```
class Word

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

attr_accessor :search 

    def self.search(search)

        # Get back JSON response
        response = Wordnik.word.get_definitions(search)

        # Parse JSON to an array of hashes?
        hash_result = JSON.parse(response)

    end  

end
```

---

When searching for a single word, I'm getting the following error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLJ6N.jpg)):

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what the value of `response`? would be good to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Wordnik.word.get_definitions(search)`, an Array of Hashes is returned, not a JSON string. Remove the line:

```
hash_result = JSON.parse(response)
```

Also having your API key publicly available on Github is probably not a good idea.